# Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration. in spring boot migration project

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am working on the spring boot migration project from spring mvc+webflow to spring boot. During runtime, I am getting the below error.

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START ***************************
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of constructor in
> com.geodan.lgr.support.ExtendedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator required a
> bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your
> configuration.

Class: ExtendedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator

Constructor:

```
public ExtendedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(ContextSource contextSource,
            String groupSearchBase) {
        super(contextSource, groupSearchBase);
            ldapTemplate = new SpringSecurityLdapTemplate(contextSource);
        
    }
```

The parameter `String groupSearchBase` creates this error. How to make Spring not creating bean for inbuilt classes?

Comment: Spring tries to use this constructor to autowire dependencies. Is it possible for you to use another constructor to autowire ContextSource? If groupSearchBase is defined in application.properties, you can annotate it with @Value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I tried using value from application.properties with @Value annotation .But,is is still not working..Also, From  this constructor,we are calling the super constructor..Is there way to stop creating spring bean for inbuilt java classes ? Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know for sure. Usually spring boot do not create bean for every class. It creates beans for classes annotated with Controller, Service, Repository or Component.

Comment: can you add a qualifier to this string and then add bean with the same qualifier? if i am correct, that string came from some similar strategy from xml configuration, is that right?

Comment: Use the @Value("${property.name}") on the parameter on the method signature - this should solve it.